# PHP SECURITY dynamic generated user hash password on every login or hash system changes

Tags: php, security, model-view-controller, passwords, salt

I'm knowing this site http://www.openwall.com/phpass/, but idea is on salt on mainly system.

Example, ZEND use system('uname -a') and it's hashed to md5() for using ROW LEVEL user SALT encryption. This is combination of user password, user login name/email address and server name as sha1/md5/...

But, my idea is generate **DYNAMIC SALT** instead STATIC SALT such as system('uname -a'). Example, every time when user is logged in, SALT has been changed but not user password.

For more security reasons, i'm needing dynamicaly changes salt on database or external file on daily basis or using third-party such as checking data from another server for salting?

What are best method for securing user sensible data on users database table and currents login. Cookie also is very bad secure options for me. It's must works such as PayPal API Tokenize and user id...

I'm using current:

1. salt from every user
2. salt from system hashed
3. hashed combination of user password, user salt and system salt
4. SHA-512 crypt() or bcrpyt() class
5. dynamically salt ? idea?

Comment: This question isn't clear (at least to me), but it *sounds* like a bad idea.

Comment: maybe is solution to use for every user customised type of encryption + salt of user + password (e.x. user A has MD5()+SHA1()+SHA256, but user B has SHA256()+SHA256+salt) and store type of encryption not on DATABASE, store on flat file and compare them for getting which types of encryptions each users use. A source code for reading types of encrpytions is also decoded like base64_encode. this will be to find and hard an attacker for finding on which method using encrpytion to store user database.

Comment: I don’t see how this “dynamic salt” would increase the security. Instead, this rather adds complexity without any significant benefit. Because as the salt needs to remembered for password verification, you would need to remember every salt ever used to be able to reproduce the stored hash.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

I think you are missing a key fact about re-hashing the password. To do it, you would have to store it in a *recoverable form*. Thus, creating even greater security risk, if system is compromised.

Here is what i would do:

- make passwords expire in 60 days (or, you can choose some other number, just not too often).
- each time user sets **new password**, you generate a random salt
- build hash with `crypt()`, using `CRYPT_SHA512` or `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` hashing algorithms
- set a bit higher amount of rounds .. 20'000 should be enough
- store the whole result that `crypt()` returns in the `hash` field in db.

Also you might benefit for reading: [Properly Salting Passwords, The Case Against Pepper](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/04/properly-salting-passwords-case-against.html).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the salt doesn't improve anything.

The point is: you always need to store salt and hash together somewhere because when you compare the password input with the hash you need to hash the input - obvious, right?

So this is the point: even if you change the salt after every login and do some weird re-hashing of the password it changes nothing because as soon as an attacker gets the database he has both hash and salt (if it's stored there together, which is necessary if you always use a different salt for each user which is something you should do).

A far more better way is extending the hashing by using 1000-10000 rounds of hashing as well as a long salt (you can easy use 512 bytes for the salt). These are better tip's than doing some re-hashing.

But anyway: if you really want to improve your PHP application you should focus on avoiding security issues like SQL injection, XSS, CSRF, RFI, LFI, file disclosure, RCE, etc - if an attacker gets access to the server he can simply backdoor the login script to send him an e-mail containing the plaintext credentials every time someone tries to login. (Well, you can also avoid this if you use a challenge-response authentication implemented in javascript like CRAM-MD5 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication or using RSA (also implemented in JS) to securely send login data).

Comment: Ok, but you are forgot using key stretching to slow down password hash generation?

Answer (score 0):

Salt is only used to prevent against precomputation attacks, such as Rainbow Tables. Thus if someone wants to bruteforce the hashes, they actually have to compute them one at a time at runtime. (and not merely do a lookup in a database of pre-computed hashed values)

It's not really clear what the problem is that you're trying to solve. You just say:

"For more security reasons, i'm needing dynamicaly changes salt"

If that problem is precomputation attacks, then just have a normal salt. If it is not a precomputation attack, then salt is almost surely the wrong solution.